# Сортировать элементы с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Есть элементы со значениями

```html
<ul class="error_sorting">                    <li>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="1" max="100">1%</progress></li>
<li>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="1" max="100">1%</progress></li>
<li>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="80" max="100">80%</progress></li>
<li>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="10" max="100">10%</progress></li>
<li>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-warning" value="1" max="100">1%</progress></li>                                                                  </ul>
```

хочу отсортировать список

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var $elements = $('li progress value');
   var $target = $('.error_sorting');
    
   $elements.sort(function (a, b) {
    var an = $(a).text(),
     bn = $(b).text();
     
    if (an && bn) {
     return an.toUpperCase().localeCompare(bn.toUpperCase());
    }
     
    return 0;
   });
    
   $elements.detach().appendTo($target);
 });
```

но видимо, что-то делаю не так. не сортирует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, что Вы рассчитываете получить таким селектором: `$('li progress value')`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $elements = $('ul.error_sorting > li');
  var $target = $('.error_sorting');

  $elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = parseInt($(a).find('progress').attr('value')),
      bn = parseInt($(b).find('progress').attr('value'));
    return an - bn;
  });

  $elements.detach().appendTo($target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="error_sorting">
  <li>
    <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="1" max="100"> 1 % </progress></li>
  <li>
    <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="1" max="100"> 1 % </progress></li>
  <li>
    <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="80" max="100"> 80 % </progress></li>
  <li>
    <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-danger" value="10" max="100"> 10 % </progress></li>
  <li>
    <progress class="progress progress-striped progress-warning" value="1" max="100"> 1 % </progress></li>
</ul>
```